# Abstract Algebra Matrix Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

The matrix group G = SL(n, $\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in M(n, \mathbb{R})\} \text{ acts on } X= R^n$ by left matrix multiplication:
$\tau _A(x) = A\cdot x (\text{matrix product }(n \times n ) \cdot (n \times 1) = (n \times 1) )$
if we regard vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n \text{ as } n \times 1$ column matrices. There is at least one trivial orbit $G * 0 = {0}$ because the $\tau_A$ are linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that this action is transitive on the complementary set $X = \mathbb{R}^n \sim \{0\}$ , so there are just two orbits.

Comment: Can you prove that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Now, I'm thinking that if I show that the vector $e_1 = col(1,0,...,0)$ can be moved to any other nonzero vector x by a suitably chosen $A \in SL$ that should suffice.  I also know that $A \cdot e_1 =$ (the first column of A) for any $A \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$.  But, I'm stuck... Help!

Comment: Can you make $A\cdot e_1$ *any* non-zero vector by choosing $A$ carefully?

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach that part of the proof.  I know that's what I have to do, however.

Comment: Think of a change of basis matrix

Comment: Ok, let $e_1$ be the first column of the matrix.  I show that $e_1 \cdot \mathbb{I} = e_1$.  Then, I choose some invertible change of basis matrix, call it $\mathbb{P}$.  If I multiply this matrix by my vector ($\mathbb{P} \cdot e_1= e_2$).  Can I conclude that $X = \mathbb{R} \sim {0}$ for all $e_1 \neq {0}$.  Therefore, $\mathbb{R^n}$ is the union of two orbits.  This is my thought process.

Comment: It is true only when $n>1$.

Answer (score 2):

A group action is transitive if for any $x,y \in X$, there exists $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$.

Given $x,y \in \boldsymbol{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$, let

$$ g = \frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert^2}y x^T $$

where $x^T$ is the transpose of $x$. Then

$$ gx = \frac{x^T x}{\Vert x \Vert^2} y = y. $$

It quickly follows that there are only two orbits because all nonzero elements of $\boldsymbol{R}^n$ are in the same orbit.